# Modyfing already avalable json file with faker

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, faker

I have a json file which stores the data from mongodb in a array format i want to change some fields in it example email, phone number etc.How can i do it using nodejs and faker?
Exaple of one data.json file

```
  {
_id: 54522,
roles: [ [Object] ],
__v: 48,
name: { last: 'Coke', first: 'Colay' },
cv: {
  _id: 54522,
  updatedAt: Z,
  createdAt: 2Z,
  educationEntries: [Array],
  workEntries: [Array]
},
unverifiedEmail: null,
unverifiedPhoneNumber: null,
phoneNumberVerificationCode: null,
phoneNumber: '8754552512',
password: 'expected',
emailVerificationCode: 'null',
smoochUserId: '2b390',
},
```

I want to change phonenumber emailverification and unverfiedEmail entries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What was the problem? The task looks straight forward: read file, parse json, update fields with faker API calls, serialize, save file.

Comment: Im very noob just getting started with node.
So facing basic issues.

Comment: Well, then start with some basic tutorials. Keep SO for cases when you have tried something and bumped into some specific issue you can't solve.